# Use a Variable From Expression In It's Callback

Tags: javascript, jquery

A lot of the stuff I find when searching for this starts talking about Ajax so I'm not even sure what I'm trying todo is possible.

I have the following JavaScript:

```
function getFruit(callback) {
    var result;

    result = "banana";

    // Make sure the callback is a function​
    if (typeof callback === "function") {
    // Call it, since we have confirmed it is callable​
        callback();
    }

    return result;
}

getFruit(function(){
    console.log(getFruit());
}
```

I simply want to pass the current value of result to the callback function so that it can be used there.

Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the `result` as parameter to the `callback` function.

```js
function getFruit(callback) {
  var result = "banana";

  if (typeof callback === "function") {
    callback(result);
  }
}

getFruit(function(parameter) {
  console.log(parameter);
})
```

Comment: Why is the statement return result required?

Comment: @RahulArora, Thats not required, as it is part of OP's code hence left it (now removed)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to pass it as callback parameter:

```js
function getFruit(callback) {
    var result;

    result = "banana";

    // Make sure the callback is a function​
    if (typeof callback === "function") {
    // Call it, since we have confirmed it is callable​
        callback(result);
    }

    return result;
}

getFruit(function(result){
    alert(result);
});
```

---

Other way (since it's not async function) is to create global variable and than use it:

```js
var result;

function getFruit(callback) {
    result = "banana";

    // Make sure the callback is a function​
    if (typeof callback === "function") {
    // Call it, since we have confirmed it is callable​
        callback();
    }
}

getFruit(function(){
    alert(result);
});
```

Comment: Just because the function is synchronous isn't an excuse to create a function with side effects.

Comment: return result is not required in your first case

Comment: Thank you for an alternate way.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
function getFruit(callback) {
    var result;

    result = "banana";

    // Make sure the callback is a function​
    if (typeof callback === "function") {
    // Call it, since we have confirmed it is callable​
        callback(result);
    }


}

getFruit(function(response){
    console.log(response);
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your help in this question.